# React and onClick in div or span and possible cons

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to find information about this but I couldn't.

My question is related to possible performance issues, accessibility, anti-patterns or **cons** of using onClick() in `span/divs` instead of a clickable element like `a/button`.

Without entering in an opinionated conversation, are there some concerns to be aware of? Or, can I use them indistinctly.

All the comments will be much appreciated. The idea is to have e better understanding and usage.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/button_role

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big issue is regarding accessibility.

If you would create a legit button from a div or a span, you would have to do a lot of things the native elements do for you, for example:

- Being focusable
- Getting correctly read by screen readers
- Works with other browser tools such as vimium.
- for links, making sure the browser exposes "open in new tab"-options and similar.

and a ton more

It is possible though, I think react-native-web does it. But long story short, *don't*. Just reset styles for `a` and `button`, and use `a` for stuff that changes the url, and `button` for the rest.